# Pullback of a Special $2$-Form.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $\phi : D^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth map from $D^2 = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||x|| \leq 1 \}$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I think there are two special $2$-forms, $f dx dy$ and $-f dx dy$ $D^2$ that this map induces, corresponding to a choice of normal vector at each point in the image of $D^2$ (it could self intersect, so this isn't quite right). Then
$$ \int_{D^2} f dx dy $$
should be the surface area of the image of $D^2$ (suppose $\phi$ is injective so that we do not have it folding on itself).

> **Question:** Can someone give an explicit formula for these two forms in terms of $\phi$?

Now, I suspect that, whenever we have a map into $\mathbb{R}^n$ from an $n-1$ dimensional manifold and given an orientability assumption, we have an induced form which will give rise to some generalization of surface area. If this is indeed true, could you explain a bit about how this might be generalized (I can work out the details myself)?

Comment: I meant $D^2$, I'll fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is the area element on the embedded surface, which is the length of the cross product of the two partial derivatives of $\phi$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$:
$$
f = |\partial_x\phi\times \partial_y\phi |.
$$

For the general case in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the set of partial derivatives of $\phi$ give a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. $f$ would be the hyper-volume of the parallelogram made by these vectors.

Comment: Thanks, @stochastic. Is $f dx dy$ also the pullback of a differential form with a nice formula?

Comment: @DeanYoung I don't think so. Imagine this surface self-intersects, then this differential form in $\mathbb{R}^3$ wouldn't be single-valued.

Comment: @DeanYoung: No, there is no $2$-form on $\Bbb R^3$ whose restriction to an arbitrary (smooth) surface is the area $2$-form of that surface. (The situation is very different in complex geometry!)